# JavaFX Observable List only one property with value true

Tags: javafx

I would like to ask you, there is the simple way to add constraint to Observable list that are only one value true of property.

For example:

I Have an observable list of Persons.   The class person has boolean Property "isKing" and string property "guild".  It can be only one king for each guild.

Sure, I can ( and I know how)  add an listener  to  change value of this property for others persons if new king will be added. But there is other way ??

( there is no database in local aplication to manage data integrations...)

Comment: I would create a method to determine if the list has a king. Then you just use an if statement if(hasKing()){//do nothing} else{add(Person)//who is king}

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem like such a property should be part of the elements of the list, but instead should be just an external value. In the example you suggest, you could create a separate class that encapsulated your list and the king:

```
public class Guild {

    private final ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<Person> king = new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<>();

    private final ObservableList<Person> members = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    public ObservableList<Person> getMembers() {
        return members ;
    }

    public ReadOnlyObjectProperty<Person> kingProperty() {
        return king.getReadOnlyProperty();
    }

    public Person getKing() {
        return kingProperty().get();
    }

    public void setKing(Person king) {
        if (! population.contains(king)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("king must be a member of the guild");
        }
        this.king.set(king);
    }
}
```

If the situation is more complex (e.g. a single population and multiple guilds, each with a king) the same basic idea should be feasible: define a model class that encapsulates whatever data structures you need, for example an `ObservableList<Person> population` and an `ObservableMap<String, Person> kings`, the latter keeping a single king for each guild.

Here is a more complex example:

Person.java:

```
package model;

import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;

public class Person {

    private final StringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty();
    private final StringProperty guild = new SimpleStringProperty();

    public Person(String name, String guild) {
        setName(name);
        setGuild(guild);
    }

    public final StringProperty nameProperty() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public final String getName() {
        return this.nameProperty().get();
    }

    public final void setName(final String name) {
        this.nameProperty().set(name);
    }

    public final StringProperty guildProperty() {
        return this.guild;
    }

    public final String getGuild() {
        return this.guildProperty().get();
    }

    public final void setGuild(final String guild) {
        this.guildProperty().set(guild);
    }

}
```

DataModel.java:

```
package model;

import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.MapChangeListener.Change;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.collections.ObservableMap;

public class DataModel {

    private final ObservableMap<String, Person> kings = FXCollections.observableHashMap() ;
    private final ObservableList<Person> population = FXCollections.observableArrayList() ;

    public DataModel() {

        // if a current king switches guild, remove them as king:
        ChangeListener<String> guildListener = (obs, oldGuild, newGuild) -> 
            kings.remove(oldGuild);
        kings.addListener((Change<? extends String, ? extends Person> c) -> {
            if (c.wasAdded()) {
                c.getValueAdded().guildProperty().addListener(guildListener);
            }
            if (c.wasRemoved()) {
                c.getValueRemoved().guildProperty().removeListener(guildListener);
            }
        });
    }

    public ObservableList<Person> getPopulation() {
        return population ;
    }

    public ObservableMap<String, Person> getKings() {
        return FXCollections.unmodifiableObservableMap(kings);
    }

    public void makeKing(Person person) {
        kings.put(person.getGuild(), person);
    }

}
```

ConstrainedModelDemo.java:

```
package ui;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.ComboBoxTableCell;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import model.DataModel;
import model.Person;

public class ConstrainedModelDemo extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        DataModel model = new DataModel();

        List<String> guilds = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 5).mapToObj(i -> "Guild "+i).collect(Collectors.toList());
        Random rng = new Random();
        List<Person> population = IntStream.rangeClosed(1,  100).mapToObj(i -> new Person("Person "+i, guilds.get(rng.nextInt(guilds.size())))).collect(Collectors.toList());

        model.getPopulation().setAll(population);

        TableView<Person> table = new TableView<>();
        table.setEditable(true);
        table.getItems().addAll(population);


        table.getColumns().add(column("Name", Person::nameProperty));
        TableColumn<Person, String> guildColumn = column("Guild", Person::guildProperty);
        guildColumn.setCellFactory(ComboBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(guilds.toArray(new String[guilds.size()])));
        table.getColumns().add(guildColumn);

        TableColumn<Person, Boolean> kingCol = new TableColumn<>("King");
        kingCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> {
            Person p = cellData.getValue();
            return Bindings.createBooleanBinding(() -> 
                p == model.getKings().get(p.getGuild()), p.guildProperty(), model.getKings());
        });

        kingCol.setCellFactory(tc -> new TableCell<Person, Boolean>() {
            private final CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox();

            {
                checkBox.setOnAction(e -> {
                    if (checkBox.isSelected()) {
                        model.makeKing(table.getItems().get(getIndex()));
                    } else {
                        model.getKings().remove(table.getItems().get(getIndex()).getGuild());
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            protected void updateItem(Boolean item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                if (empty) {
                    setGraphic(null);
                } else {
                    checkBox.setSelected(item);
                    setGraphic(checkBox);
                }
            }
        });
        table.getColumns().add(kingCol);

        TableView<String> kingTable = new TableView<>();
        kingTable.getItems().addAll(guilds);
        kingTable.getColumns().add(column("Guild", guild -> new SimpleStringProperty(guild)));
        kingTable.getColumns().add(column("King", guild -> Bindings.createStringBinding(() -> {
            if (guild == null) return null ;
            Person king = model.getKings().get(guild);
            if (king == null) return null ;
            return king.getName() ;
        }, model.getKings())));

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(table);
        root.setRight(kingTable);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 600);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private <S,T> TableColumn<S,T> column(String title, Function<S, ObservableValue<T>> prop) {
        TableColumn<S,T> col = new TableColumn<>(title);
        col.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> prop.apply(cellData.getValue()));
        return col ;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```